# Azure CLI - How to Undelete a Storage Blob with Soft-Delete and Versioning enabled

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am using the Azure CLI to add blobs to my storage account. Via the Azure CLI, I am successfully able to soft delete blobs; I can confirm this by viewing the soft-deleted blobs on the Azure Portal. I want to restore a blob that I delete via the Azure CLI again, but I am having trouble. I have attempted to use the `az storage blob undelete` command to do this. It is reportedly successful - I know this by adding the `--verbose` flag and seeing the 200 HTTP Status returned from the API call that the CLI triggers. The response is:

```
{
  "undeleted": null
}
```

And when I look at the list of blobs in the Azure Portal again, there is no indication that the blob was actually restored/undeleted. Has anyone else had success using the *undelete* Azure CLI command previously?

Here is some terminal output; hopefully it is helpful in understanding what I'm trying to do:

```
PS C:\Users\admin> az storage blob list --account-name azartbackupstore01 -c backupcontainer01 -o table
Name                                                                 IsDirectory    Blob Type    Blob Tier    Length    Content Type              Last Modified              Snapshot
-------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------  -----------  -----------  --------  ------------------------  -------------------------  ----------
20/20162F8E84F43EEAAEC0DB0010545C32D8D1A0CF60284CA2E9A57884B55C2445                 BlockBlob                 47        application/octet-stream  2021-08-05T15:25:59+00:00
92/92D536261E45E93DB4A8F063A98102BF443DD7EC16B1075F7D13A1A326544035                 BlockBlob                 11458     application/octet-stream  2021-08-05T15:22:47+00:00

PS C:\Users\admin> az storage blob delete --account-name azartbackupstore01 -c backupcontainer01 --name 20/20162F8E84F43EEAAEC0DB0010545C32D8D1A0CF60284CA2E9A57884B55C2445

PS C:\Users\admin> az storage blob undelete --account-name azartbackupstore01 -c backupcontainer01 --name 20/20162F8E84F43EEAAEC0DB0010545C32D8D1A0CF60284CA2E9A57884B55C2445
{
  "undeleted": null
}

PS C:\Users\admin> az storage blob list --account-name azartbackupstore01 -c backupcontainer01 -o table
Name                                                                 IsDirectory    Blob Type    Blob Tier    Length    Content Type              Last Modified              Snapshot
-------------------------------------------------------------------  -------------  -----------  -----------  --------  ------------------------  -------------------------  ----------
92/92D536261E45E93DB4A8F063A98102BF443DD7EC16B1075F7D13A1A326544035                 BlockBlob                 11458     application/octet-stream  2021-08-05T15:22:47+00:00
```

Comment: I executed above statements with my own storage account and for me the `undelete` command worked. I also get the same response when executing the `undelete` command. Are you sure you have soft-deletion enabled for blobs in your storage account?
On the [Microsoft Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_blob_undelete) it states: 
_Attempting to undelete a blob or snapshot that is not soft deleted will succeed without any changes._

Comment: @Melissa that's probably because you didn't enable versioning for blobs when you created your storage account. My issue occurs when I do this for a storage account that has versioning enabled for data protection; when I do it on a storage account that doesn't have it enabled, everything works just fine. I think that I need to specify a specific version of the blob to restore/undelete, but I'm not sure how to do that via the Azure CLI - if it's even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently when you have soft-delete and versioning enabled on blobs, something weird is happening (even in the Azure portal where the blob is shown as deleted but the blob state is `null`, and the versions of the deleted blob are still shown as active).
But I found some kind of a workaround.

In short:

1. Get the (latest) versionId of the blob you want to undelete
2. Get the blob URI and add the versionId and SAS token as query parameters to the URI.
3. Copy the blob where source URI is the deleted blob including `versionId` (I found this solution in the code [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/soft-delete-blob-manage?tabs=dotnet#restore-soft-deleted-blobs-when-versioning-is-enabled-1))

When a versioned blob is soft-deleted, it will show up with the command:

```
az storage blob list --account-name azartbackupstore01 -c backupcontainer01 -o table --include v
```

I only added the `--include (v)ersion` at the end which will show all versions of the blobs. The `--include (d)eleted` will not work, because the blob somehow does not have have a state deleted.

Here is how I've done it:

```
$blobName="20/20162F8E84F43EEAAEC0DB0010545C32D8D1A0CF60284CA2E9A57884B55C2445"
$containerName="backupcontainer01"
$accountName="azartbackupstore01"
$sas="replace with your sas token"

# query all blobs where name equals $blobName, and reverse sort by versionId (which is the date) so most recent will be the first in the list
$versionId=az storage blob list --account-name $accountName -c $containerName --include v -o json --query "reverse(sort_by([?name=='$blobName'], &versionId))[0].versionId"
$blobUriRoot=az storage blob url --account-name $accountName -c $containerName --name $blobName
# The blobUriRoot and versionId variables are outputted with additional quotes, so these need to be replaced.
$blobUri=$($blobUriRoot + "?versionId=" + $versionId).Replace('"', "")

$blobUriWithSas = $blobUri + "&" + $sas
az storage blob copy start --account-name $accountName --destination-blob $blobName --destination-container $containerName --source-uri $blobUriWithSas
```

After running above commands, the specified blob is active again.

Comment: I'll dive into this shortly, but just wanted to quickly say thank you for the effort you've made in helping me - it's super appreciated. I'll follow up afterwards!

Comment: This is perfect. Exactly what I needed. I see how the logic parallels that of which was included in the Microsoft documentation that recommends using the .NET SDK (you linked to it). My goodness. Thank you again!!