# ListBlobs does not list Deleted blobs

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to list all deleted blobs from an Azure Storage Account. Here is my code:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Auth;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

var blobClient = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials("accountname", "accountkey"), true).CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("container");
var blobs = container.ListBlobs(useFlatBlobListing: true, blobListingDetails: BlobListingDetails.Deleted).ToList();
```

However, the result of `ListBlobs` is all non-deleted blobs in the container. In the Azure Portal I can clearly see there are many more deleted blobs in this container, but they are not being retrieved correctly.

How can I list only the blobs in deleted state in my container?

Edit:

I created a new container, with two blobs: `test_deleted` (which I deleted in the Azure Portal) and `test_not_deleted`. Using the newer `Azure.Blob.Storage` package, I now have the following code:

```
var client = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new StorageSharedKeyCredential(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey));
var container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
var resultSegment = container.GetBlobsAsync(states: BlobStates.Deleted, traits: BlobTraits.All).AsPages(default, 5000);

var results = new List<BlobItem>();

await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
{
    foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
    {
        results.Add(blobItem);
    }
}
```

The result contains only the not deleted blob.

[image: Azure Portal screenshot]

[image: Results view]

Comment: Are you seeing both deleted and active blobs in the result?

Comment: Using the code from my edit, I am only seeing the active blob in the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of headache and some help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683323/azure-cli-how-to-undelete-a-storage-blob-with-soft-delete-and-versioning-enabl) answer, I have figured out how to retrieve the deleted blobs. For some reason, if both versioning and soft-delete are enabled, the blobs you retrieve do not have the `Deleted` property set to `true`. Instead, their `VersionId` property will be `null`.

It seems that when `BlobStates.DeletedWithVersions` is used, all blobs are retrieved, but for deleted blobs, `VersionId` will be `null`. Here is the seemingly working code which retrieves all the blobs marked deleted:

```
var client = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new StorageSharedKeyCredential(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey));
var container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("test");
var resultSegment = container.GetBlobsAsync(states: BlobStates.DeletedWithVersions, traits:BlobTraits.All).AsPages(default, 5000);

var deletedBlobs = new List<BlobItem>();

await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
{
    foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
    {
        if (blobItem.VersionId == null)
        {
            deletedBlobs.Add(blobItem);
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I needed to know if a blob was deleted on a certain day. When a blob is deleted, a new version is created. So to find the deletion day, you need to retrieve everything with the blob's name, using `BlobStates.Version`, and check the `VersionId` property of the blobs, which is a date string. This will contain the date the version was created (i.e. the blob was deleted).

```
foreach (var deletedBlob in deletedBlobs)
{
    var versions = container.GetBlobs(BlobTraits.None, BlobStates.Version, prefix: deletedBlob.Name);

    foreach(var v in versions)
    { 
        if (deletedOn == DateTime.Parse(v.VersionId))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob {deletedBlob.Name} deleted on {deletedOn}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to provide the same answer. Considering you have blob versioning enabled on the storage account, you will need to use `BlobStates.DeletedWithVersions` instead of `BlobStates.Deleted`. Please see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobstates?view=azure-dotnet#fields) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a very old NuGet package, you should upgrade to [Azure.Storage.Blobs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Storage.Blobs/).

Then use paging to get *all* the blobs as shown on [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-list?tabs=dotnet#use-a-flat-listing):

```cs
private static async Task ListBlobsFlatListing(BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient, 
                                               int? segmentSize)
{
    try
    {
        // Call the listing operation and return pages of the specified size.
        var resultSegment = blobContainerClient.GetBlobsAsync()
            .AsPages(default, segmentSize);

        // Enumerate the blobs returned for each page.
        await foreach (Azure.Page<BlobItem> blobPage in resultSegment)
        {
            foreach (BlobItem blobItem in blobPage.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Blob name: {0}", blobItem.Name);
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Use the optional [blobstates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.models.blobstates?view=azure-dotnet) parameter to specify you want to list deleted blobs

Comment: Using the `Azure.Storage.Blobs` package has the same result. Regardless of whether I supply the `states` parameter or not, `GetBlobs` always returns all non-deleted blobs:

`var client = new BlobServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{StorageAccountName}.blob.core.windows.net"), new StorageSharedKeyCredential(StorageAccountName, StorageAccountKey));
var container = client.GetBlobContainerClient("container");
var results = container.GetBlobs(states: BlobStates.Deleted).ToList();`

Comment: Using `BlobStates.All` seems to retrieve more blobs. However, every single result has the `Deleted` property as `false`.

Comment: Have you applied paging yet? Because depending on the total count of blobs inside a container not all results are fetched.

Comment: Using the code from your comment, `BlobStates.Deleted`, and a `segmentSize` of `5000`, the result is only the 43 non-deleted blobs in the container.

Comment: Soft delete and versioning are both enabled for the storage account, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I tried use `blobstate` to list uncommitted blobs.

But `GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync` with `BlobStates.Uncommitted` return same result as with `BlobStates.None`.

My code:

```
var blobHierarchyItems = await lobContainerClient
    .GetBlobsByHierarchyAsync(BlobTraits.None, blobStates);
Console.WriteLine("BlobStates " + blobStates);
foreach(var blobHierarchyItem in blobHierarchyItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Blob.Name " + blobHierarchyItem.Blob.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("Blob.Properties.LastModified " + blobHierarchyItem.Blob.Properties.LastModified);
}
```

Result:

**BlobStates Uncommitted**

> Blob.Name testing_6.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:04 +00:00

> Blob.Name testing_7.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:25 +00:00

> Blob.Name testing_8.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 13:47:46 +00:00

**BlobStates None**

> Blob.Name testing_6.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:04 +00:00

> Blob.Name testing_7.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 6:30:25 +00:00

> Blob.Name testing_8.bin Blob.Properties.LastModified 25.03.2022 13:47:46 +00:00

Do I something wrong? Thanks

Comment: This is not an answer... please, if you got a question open a new question dedicated to it. Thanks!